# How to get real part of a sympy expression?

Tags: python, sympy

In Sympy I want to get the real part of an expression, but unable to separate the real part.

The steps I have done:

```py
from sympy import *
a, b = symbols('a b')
z1 = a + b*I
z2 = simplify(expand(z1**3))
```

The `z2` output is:

```py
a**3 + 3*I*a**2*b - 3*a*b**2 - I*b**3
```

When I try to get the real part, I get this:

```py
>>> re(z2) 
re(a)**3 - 3*re(a)*im(a)**2 + 3*re(b)**2*im(b) - 3*re(a*b**2) - im(b)**3 - 3*im(a**2*b)
```

I expected `a**3 - 3*a*b**2`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sympy doesn't realize that you want `a` and `b` to be real variables, so its output assumes they are complex. If `a` and `b` are real, then terms containing `im(a)` and/or `im(b)` are 0 since there are no imaginary parts to `a` or `b`. To fix this, you should define your variables with your assumptions, i.e. tell sympy that `a` and `b` are real. Then the result will be as expected.

```py
from sympy import *
a, b = symbols("a b", real=True)
z1 = a + b*I
z2 = simplify(expand(z1**3))
print(re(z2))
```

Output:

```py
a**3 - 3*a*b**2
```

Answer (score 0):

A way to do it without setting assumptions on the symbols is:

```
In [2]: z2
Out[2]:
 3        2          2      3
a  + 3⋅ⅈ⋅a ⋅b - 3⋅a⋅b  - ⅈ⋅b

In [3]: z2i, z2r = z2.as_poly(I).all_coeffs()

In [4]: z2i
Out[4]:
   2      3
3⋅a ⋅b - b

In [5]: z2r
Out[5]:
 3        2
a  - 3⋅a⋅b
```